# want to retrieve the only Rupees value from firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, textview

You may think that this post is a duplicate but believe me i've tried all of them but that wouldn't take me anywhere near to solution.

I am a beginner & currently in a learning phase.

I want to retrieve in the textview only the `rupees` value from `standard 1st` of `School no 109` of `Gat No 14`

Here is the Database tree
[image]

Here is my code.

> java

```
    public class Collection extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView ttl;
    Button btnshw;
    DatabaseReference d2ref;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_collection);ttl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texirs);
        btnshw = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bshow);

        btnshw.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                d2ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("2018-19").child("Gat No 14")
                        .child("School no 109").child("Standard 1st");
                d2ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot dsnap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Map<String, String> map = (Map)dsnap.getValue();
                            if(map != null) {
                                String gat = dataSnapshot.child("Rupees").getValue().toString();
                                ttl.setText(gat);
                                Log.d("Tag",gat);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Please Help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :-

```
 d2ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("2018-19").child("Gat No 14")
                    .child("School no 109").child("Standard 1st");
            d2ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                      String gat = dataSnapshot.child("Rupees").getValue().toString();
                     // and set tha gat in your textView
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but can you please have a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55765225/i-want-to-get-all-the-key-in-my-spinner-then-after-that-another-key-in-another-s